# Copy and paste X, Y and Z values

Tags: modeling, interface, coordinates

In Blender 2.79 there is a new option that allow you to copy all the transform values (x, y, z) at once in the N-menu with `CTRL + ALT + C` for copy and `CTRL + ALT + V` for paste. But this seems only to work with objects in object mode, not if I want change the position of a vertex in edit mode. What could be the reason for that?!

Comment: One object has one location. How would you expect it to work in edit mode if more than one vertex is selected?

Comment: @batFINGER In my question I wrote "a vertex", how could that be "if more than one vertex is selected" ? A vertex is one vertex.

Comment: It's looks like an very new feature, maybe this functional isn't implemented yet?